# lambda if statement or do nothing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Hey I looked through some of the post but I could not find a direct answer. I am working on a pandas DataFrame which has two columns ZipCode and ZipCodePlusFour. Some of the ZipCodePlusFour cells are populated. All ZipCode cells are filled. The problem is the ZipCode has 9 digits. So I am trying to get rid of the last 4 digits of the 9 digit Zipcodes and put them in ZipCodePLusFour.

```
df['ZipCode'] = df.ZipCode.astype(str)  # just in case
df['ZipCodePlusFour'] = df.ZipCode.apply(lambda x: x[-4:] if len(x) > 5 else None)
df['ZipCode'] = df.ZipCode.apply(lambda x: x[:-4] if len(x) > 5 else
```

My problem is on the second line. The if statement does what it is supposed to do but the else should do nothing. I tried putting None but it populates the cells with None instead of leaving that value that was already in the cell.

Comment: `else x` to keep it as is

Comment: I think to solve this you should just remove the `else` part?

Comment: The logic is *if the string has 6 or more characters, trim it down to the last 4, if it has 5 characters, leave it at 5*…? Just asking in case that's maybe an off-by-one error, since if the rule is simply supposed to be "trim to a maximum of 4 characters", there's no `if..else` needed at all.

Comment: @JackParkinson can you remove else in a lambda statement?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure you can - I may have been a bit thick :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass values that are less than 5 digits length you can do it like this:

```
df['ZipCode'] = df.ZipCode.apply(lambda x: x[-4:] if len(x) > 5 else x)
```

But you can do it more simple, no need to check length:

```
df['ZipCode'] = df.ZipCode.apply(lambda x: x[-4:])
```

Answer (score 0):

All you want is to trim the strings to atmost 5 places. You can do `df.ZipCode.str[:5]`?

```
In [78]: df
Out[78]:
     ZipCode
0  123456789
1        123
2          0
```

For, 5 places zipcodes

```
In [79]: df.ZipCode.str[:5]
Out[79]:
0    12345
1      123
2        0
Name: ZipCode, dtype: object
```

For, the extra (>5) characters part in zipcodes

```
In [80]: df.ZipCode.str[5:]
Out[80]:
0    6789
1
2
Name: ZipCode, dtype: object
```